# How to call a function defined in the main context from a Python module?

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

I'd like to write a Python module that calls a function defined at the main context. Specifically, here is my "qutest.py" module pseudo-code (the call `__main__.on_setup()` does not compile):

```
def test(title):
    try:
        __main__.on_setup() # <== call on_setup() from the main scope
    except:
        print("on_setup not found")

~ ~ ~
```

And here is my main module:

```
from qutest import *

def on_setup():
    print("on_setup")

test("My first test")
~ ~ ~
```

The goal is that the `test()` invocation would call `on_setup()` defined at the **main** context. How can I code it inside my `qutest.py` module?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Add `import __main__`?

Comment: It looks like it may be best to pass `on_setup` as argument to `test`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip `import __main__`. If I add it to the module (`qutest`), the call `__main__.on_setup()` works correctly. So, this seems to solve my problem.